# uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I called an API data from a weather provider website, I also used the geocoding package from Flutter, but when i try to run the app there was an error that said :

```
Note: C:\Users\<my-PC-name>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geocoding_android-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\Geocoding.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

debug is still running, but API data is not retrieved, and the application shows no errors, above I assume there is a problem in the geocoding file & The geocoding file contains

```
class Geocoding {
    private final Context androidContext;

    /**
     * Uses the given {@code androidContext} to execute geocoding features
     *
     * @param androidContext the context to use when requesting geocoding features
     */
    Geocoding(Context androidContext) {
        this.androidContext = androidContext;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of Address objects matching the supplied address string.
     *
     * @param address the address string for the search
     * @param locale the desired Locale for the query results
     * @return a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.
     * @throws java.io.IOException if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs.
     */
    List<Address> placemarkFromAddress(String address, Locale locale) throws IOException {

        final Geocoder geocoder = createGeocoder(androidContext, locale);
        return geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of Address objects matching the supplied coordinates.
     *
     * @param latitude the latitude point for the search
     * @param longitude the longitude point for the search
     * @param locale the desired Locale for the query results
     * @return a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.
     * @throws IOException if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs.
     */
    List<Address> placemarkFromCoordinates(
            double latitude,
            double longitude,
            Locale locale) throws IOException {

        final Geocoder geocoder = createGeocoder(androidContext, locale);
        return geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5);
    }

    private static Geocoder createGeocoder(Context androidContext, @Nullable Locale locale) {
        return (locale != null)
                ? new Geocoder(androidContext, locale)
                : new Geocoder(androidContext);
    }
}
```

I don't understand the meaning of Xlint, but before that I added a '`uses-permission`' in '`android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`'
saya menambahkan

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

This is used to provide location access which will later be approved by the user, because the application requires location access

I also created a service which will later retrieve the API data and store it in a JSON file as below

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:myapp/models/weather_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class WeatherService {
  static const BASE_URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  final String apikey;

  WeatherService(this.apikey);

  Future<Weather> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('$BASE_URL?q=$cityName&appid=$apikey&units=metrics'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Weather.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load weather");
    }
  }

  Future<String> getCurrentCity() async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    List<Placemark> Placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    String? city = Placemarks[0].locality;

    return city ?? '';
  }
}
```

here I use openweathermap as the API service provider, is there anything wrong in my code, and how to solve the problem, thank you

can display API data that has been successfully called and can resolve problems when running the code